# How do you get a prompt to pop up after the calculate function

Tags: javascript, prompt

How do you get the "pizzaDelivery" prompt to pop after the "function calculate" has done it's thing?

I'm new to Javascript so little words would be prefered.

```
  function askPizzaDelivery() {
var pizzaDelivery = prompt ("Do you want your order to be delivered for $5? - Type in either 'yes' or 'no' depending on if you want it to be delivered. ");
if (pizzaDelivery == 'yes') {
   var deliver = 5;
   total = orderTotalPrice + deliver;  //adds delivery cost
   alert ('The total cost of your order including delivery is $' + orderTotalPrice);
} else if (pizzaDelivery == 'no') {
   alert ('The cost of your order with no delivery is $' + total);
}
}
```

Comment: Side note: if you want a built-in yes/no popup, you are better off using [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) instead of `prompt`. And put your `yes` in the if in quotes like you have done with the `'no'`

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but all I can say is that if you use prompt right after calculate, you will get the prompt after calculate. Btw, where's the pizzadelivery function?

Comment: `pizzaDelivery` isn't a function, it's just the string that's returned by the `prompt()`.

Comment: your posted code is working only problem is you do not have total ,orderTotalPrice declared and initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code inside a function and call it at the end of the calcualte function:

```
function calculate()    //Function for the cost of the order
{
    orderTotalPrice = (totalPlain*pizzaPrice + totalGourmet*pizzaPriceGourmet);  //order total+amount of pizzas ordered * pizza price
    alert("Total cost of pizzas is: $" + orderTotalPrice.toFixed(2) );  //Display order cost as "$"0.00
    askPizzaDelivery();
}

function askPizzaDelivery() {
    var pizzaDelivery = prompt ("Do you want your order to be delivered for $5? - enter either 'yes' or 'no'");
    if (pizzaDelivery == yes) {
    ...
}
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: This is what I have, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas why?

Comment: I'll put it in the main part above